# I'm having trouble loading and parsing XML with jQuery, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I'm attempting to read settings from an XML file. I think I am not loading the object correctly or possibly my selector is not doing what I think it is. The log message inside of the `appendImages` function does not execute, I'm not sure why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "banner_slider/settings.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: startSlider
  });
});

function startSlider(xml) {
  var bWidth = $('#banner').width(), bHeight = $('#banner').height();
  bWidth += 'px';
  bHeight += 'px';
  $('#banner').attr( 'style', 'height: '+bHeight );
  $('#banner').attr( 'style', 'width: '+bWidth );
  $('#banner img').attr( 'id', 'origImg');
  appendImages( bWidth, bHeight, xml );
  $('#origImg').remove();
  $('#banner').cycle();
}

function appendImages( bWidth, bHeight, xml ) {
  console.log('appendImages executed');
  $(xml).find('img').each(function() {
    var path = $(this).text(); 
    console.log('path: '+path); 
    $('#banner').append('<img width="'+bWidth+'" height="'+bHeight+'" src="'+path+'" />');
  });
}
```

XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<images>
    <img>test1</img>
    <img>test2</img>
    <img>test3</img>
</images>
```

Comment: Your xml is invalid, the last `<images>` should be `</images>`.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the invalid XML (face+palm). However, I'm still not entering into the XML selector. I replaced code in `appendImages` in the original question. `console.log('appendImages executed');` returns to the console correctly, `console.log('path: '+path);` does not return anything to the console.

Comment: You didn't set any units for your width and height style in `#banner`

Comment: Units added, however units or not I am still not pulling information from the XML file correctly.

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors?

Comment: Also does `startSlider` execute?

Comment: `startSlider` and `appendImages` execute log statements. A log statement inside the `$(xml)` selector within `appendImages` does not execute.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine see http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/yQLx6/

Comment: Thanks, I think I am experiencing a server-side issues with the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the syntax errors were fixed by Musa, my code functioned as expected. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "banner_slider/settings.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: startSlider
  });
});

function startSlider(xml) {
  var bWidth = $('#banner').width(), bHeight = $('#banner').height();
  bWidth += 'px';
  bHeight += 'px';
  $('#banner').attr( 'style', 'height: '+bHeight );
  $('#banner').attr( 'style', 'width: '+bWidth );
  $('#banner img').attr( 'id', 'origImg');
  appendImages( bWidth, bHeight, xml );
  $('#origImg').remove();
  $('#banner').cycle();
}

function appendImages( bWidth, bHeight, xml ) {
  console.log('appendImages executed');
  $(xml).find('img').each(function() {
    var path = $(this).text(); 
    console.log('path: '+path); 
    $('#banner').append('<img width="'+bWidth+'" height="'+bHeight+'" src="'+path+'" />');
  });
}
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<images>
    <img>test1</img>
    <img>test2</img>
    <img>test3</img>
</images>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/yQLx6/

Answer (score 1):

try this, you have to pass the response to the success handler, i have modified your code to remove the settings but you can add them and also use [`.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) instead of using jquery's DOM traversal methods to traverse through the xml

```
 function startSlider(xml) {  
     console.log("xml recieved successfully");
     console.log(window.$xml);
  appendImages(window.$xml);

}

function appendImages( xml ) {
  console.log('appendImages executed');
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $imgArr = $xml.find( "img" );
    console.log($imgArr);
    $($imgArr).each(function(i,j){
    console.log($(j).text());

    });

}
$(function(){
    window.$xml="<images><img>test1</img><img>test2</img><img>test3</img></images>";

$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/echo/json/",
     dataType: "xml",  
     success: startSlider(window.$xml)
 });
});
```

[DMEO](http://jsfiddle.net/xMEmH/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to properly hand over your data from ajax callback to your function.

```
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        startSlider(data);
   }
```

Check out this demo on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ymdEj/)